# Add node to XElement as last node

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the following xml:

```
<node>
  <other/>
  <other2/>
</node>
```

How to add a node2 after the end of node using Linq?

I have tried many code combinations with no luck. The most evident for me, assuming this XNode is contained in node variable is

```
node.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(node2);
```

But it give me as result:

```
<node>
  <other/>
  <other2/>
</node>
```

And I want:

```
<node>
  <other/>
  <other2/>
</node>
<node2/>
```

Best regards.

Comment: I suspect you had the wrong value for `node`. I suspect it was a reference to the *parent* of `<node>`. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and I'm sure it'll be easy to fix.

Comment: What you want has 2 root elements which is not possible within an XElement, encapsulate them within a new root node?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's longer and complex than what i explain, as i'm creating a word xml document and posting the full data here will make it hard to read. I can assure I have a valid node with that structure.

Comment: @AlexK. Ok, that's what I was starting to suspect. Should I create a temporary XDocument container with another root to hold them both then?

Comment: @Oscar: I'm not asking for your actual code. I'm asking for a short but complete program which reproduces the problem. I suspect that while trying to do so, you may well find out what's wrong with your real code...

Comment: You could `currentXml = new XElement("newroot", currentXml, new XElement("node2"));`

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks!, that's what I'm trying right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new root node, insert node as a child of the new root node, then add node2 to the end of the new root node.
Then, the XML that you want is the .innerXML of your new root.